# Encryption image pixels using RSA encryption (python)

Tags: python, image-processing, encryption, rsa

I'm using python to encrypt an image pixel by pixel to make whole-new image with same size and other people can't see the old image.

I have write demo RSA encryption using small number of P and Q

but when I encrypt the image pixel by pixel, the RGB value will be flood with value more 255 therefore I can't print the new image properly

```
encrypt_img  = Image.open("./images/index.jpeg")
encrypt_img_pixels = encrypt_img.load()
encrypt_row,encrypt_col=encrypt_img.size

print("Encrypting picture with RSA public key (e:",E,"n:",N,")...")
for i in range(encrypt_row):
    for j in range(encrypt_col):
        red,green,blue = encrypt_img_pixels[i,j]
        C1=power(red,E,N)
        C2=power(green,E,N)
        C3=power(blue,E,N)
        encrypt_img_pixels[i,j]=(int(C1),int(C2),int(C3))
encrypt_img.save("./output/rsa_encrypt_output.png")
```

If I mod the result to have the proper image, I can't decrypt it since the value have been change

```
        C1=C1%256
        C2=C2%256
        C3=C3%256
```

So the question is are there anyway to encrypt picture pixel by pixel with RSA using python?

Comment: The maximum length of bytes that can be encrypted with RSA depends on the RSA key length. For example: using a 2048 bit RSA key you can encrypt 2048 / 8 = 256 bytes (when using **UNSECURE** RSA in textbook mode). So for larger amounts of data you need to use a **hybrid** encryption where the encryption is done with AES and the AES key is encrypted by RSA. That way you can encrypt much larger amounts of data.

Comment: You can XOR the bytes with any pseudo-random stream generated from a key. This is reversible.

A more exotic method would be to swap the bytes using some scheme, possibly combined with XORs. This is also reversible.